# Can't Find PLIST I Created in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsbundle, property-list

In my app, I am using Plists for making different lists.  I want each Plist to be one list, and to be able to view all available lists in a TableView.  To create the Plist I am using this:

```
NSString *plistname = [alertController.textFields[0].text stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *pathFirstTime = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistname];

        [@{} writeToFile: pathFirstTime atomically: YES];
```

I went in to finder after getting the path, and verified the Plist file IS there.

I then am creating an NSArray of all the Plist in documents directory to be able to load into a TableView using this code, but it returns an empty array:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    self.files  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.files);
```

Comment: did you check if your .plist is created correctly?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I printed the path in console and went there in my finder and I can clearly see the name of it, and under "Kind" it shows Property List

Comment: If you give `nil` in `pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:` for the type, is it listed? Because the doc says it should list then all the files. I'd maybe use `NSFileManager` instead though to list the files.

Comment: @Larme No, nil returns nothing as well.  The path it gives in console when I create the file is: 

`/Users/candacebrassfield/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99876607-1F59-434F-B9BE-46390C1C4EFF/data/Containers/Data/Application/1C8FAD30-6797-445D-BBB8-610FD014B707/Documents/Lowes.plist`

Do I need to be finding a different way to list that Documents folder?

Comment: @Larme changing to NSFileManager using predicate for ends with plist worked.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me that `pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:`, since it's a `NSBundle` method list only files "loaded" at compilation time (in the bundle), that's why I did suggest to use `NSFileManager` instead.